# Pass password in Ruby script

Tags: mysql, ruby, shell

I am using mysql dump command. How do I pass the password required for it?

```
`mysqldump -uroot #{db_name} > #{tmp_local_path}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like:

```
`mysqldump -uroot -pPASSWORD #{db_name} > #{tmp_local_path}`
```

Comment: Using this it prompts to enter the password, I want to directly enter the password without using command prompt.